# Printing plot adds strange line

Tags: pgfplots, printing

I just occured a very strange problem with pgfplots. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=0:5,
    xmin=0, xmax=3,
    ymin=0, ymax=3.5,
    samples=500,
    width=11cm,
    height=6cm,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
    ytick={1},
    xtick={1}
    ]
    \addplot[red, very thick, mark=none] {x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2)};     
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This renders like this (expectedly) in every PDF reader I tried:

[image: render]

But when I print it, it looks like this (scan):

[image: print]

I printed it on different machines, different printers and different Adobe Reader versions (Acrobat Reader XI Pro and Acrobat Reader DC). The result is always the same, so it's not a driver/printer issue. Printing from Firefox is fine, but since I'm working on lecture notes that are going to be printed by a lot of people, telling everyone "don't use Adobe Reader" is not a solution.

I just want to know why this happens and what I can do to avoid it.

(I know this is a bit hard to debug because it involves printing.)

I already tried to alter the plot and discovered that as soon as I added something to the denominator that made the definition gap disappear, not only the top horizontal line disappeared, but both bottom lines too. But it is not a general definition gap problem, I have other plots with some and they are printed fine.

Comment: Have you tried any other pdf reader? (Except adobe). It could be a adobe bug if other pdf readers doesn't cause this.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I printed it with firefox and it looks fine. However, I guess Adobe Reader doesn't simply print something that is not there (and it looks like the path was just closed wherever possible), and even if, there must be a solution that works with Adobe Reader too.

Comment: Though you said it's not, this looks like a printer driver problem as PostScript operation does not lift the pen. Does it happen if you change the axis limits?

Comment: Firefox uses some extensions for pdf but it is not really a pdf reader... just includes extensions... If only adobe and not other pdf readers has the problem it is off-topic here. It is a problem to be reported at adobe's bugs. Just try one or two other pdf viewers (there ate many of them and many open source too). (Me and most of the people doesn't really know what adobe is looking for to print, since it is a closed source program.)

Comment: I tried it on three different printers from different brands and from two different PCs. And printing another plot like (x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2+(0.3*x)^2)) that makes the definition gap disappear works fine. So it has - at least in part - something to do with pgfplots.

Comment: i can't reproduce your problem. i use recent `miktex`, `pgplots` and adobe acrobat reader DC, version 2017.012.20098.

Comment: @Zarko: I have the same adobe reader version and also use miktex. `pgfplots` is version 1.15.

Comment: @percusse: I tried two alternatives of the axis limits: `ymax=10cm`, `domain=0:10`. The problem persists. (Lots of scratch paper...)

Comment: @jaytar, i use printer HP2025d, driver is (i thing so) recent one. i have no idea, what is going wrong of you. so far my experiences show, that adobe reader print exactly what you see on the screen. sorry, i can't help you any further.

Comment: @Zarko: I tried it with Lexmark M5155, Canon iR 8285 Pro and HP Officejet 8610 Pro. oh, and compiling the mwe with texlive at work creates the same problem.

Comment: @jaytar I will try it on my Lexmark CS310 in a couple of hours using opensource software. If the problem will not be reproduced there please think about reporting on adobe.

Comment: @jaytar, try if the following modification of your *mwe* works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=11cm, height=6cm,
    axis lines=left,
    xmin=0, xmax=3,
    ymin=0, ymax=3.5,
    ytick={1},
    xtick={1},
    domain=0:5, samples=500
    ]
    \addplot[red, very thick, mark=none] {x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem but fixed by losing the domain keyword (which conflicts with xmin and xmax).

Comment: @John Kormylo: Thanks, that fixed it! I'm wondering why this is happening, and why slightly altering the plot (like the function I mentioned in another comment) does not produce the error, even if both options are active.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not sure if "conflicts" is the right term, the two are separate, aren't they? (And if you remove it, the default domain of `-5:5` is used instead.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Using [clip=false, restrict y to domain 0:10], I see that you are right.  How bizarre!  OTOH, this also removes the extra lines.  Perhaps this has something to do with having x=1 as a sample point.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried to add `samples at={0, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 2, 3}`` to the plot to test your idea, but the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: How about the [restrict y to domain=0:10]?  That is a more reasonable fix.

Comment: I am having this same problem when including an eps-image produced by Mathematica. The extra lines appear ONLY in the printed version. Not when previewing the final pdf-document by TeXWorks or Adobe Reader. Not when previewing the eps-file in GhostView. Only the printed version has these extra lines. I wonder whether [this](https://superuser.com/questions/628338/strange-extra-lines-in-images-in-pdf-saved-with-ms-word-happens-with-images-f) is related.

Comment: I can confirm that `restrict` fixed my issue while `xmax,xmin` were not helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found the following solution to do the trick:
add `restrict x to domain = 0:10` and `restrict y to = 0:10` to your axis environment. The domain range should be chosen such that the full range of your plot is inculded. e.g. if you want to plot from (0:0) to (2:2) chose the domain from -1 to 3 so that the borders on the axes are plotted as well. Your MWE hence would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=0:5,
    xmin=0, xmax=3,
    ymin=0, ymax=3.5,
    samples=500,
    width=11cm,
    height=6cm,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
    ytick={1},
    xtick={1},
    restrict x to domain = 0:4,
    restrict y to domain = 0:4
    ]
    \addplot[red, very thick, mark=none] {x^2/sqrt((1-x^2)^2)};     
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was already suggested by John Kormylo in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393234/printing-plot-adds-strange-line#comment977573_393234) already, but OP didn't comment on that so far ...

Comment: Is there a way to know if I would experience this behaviour without printing?

Comment: In my case the problem also occurred when I printed it to pdf.