# Printing problem using Adobe Reader PGFPLOTS

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex

I am using PGFPLOTS to produce plots in my thesis. When I print out the document using Adobe Reader, some additional weird lines appears (in small box)  in some plots (not all) created by using PGFPLOTS. There is no problem when I use different PDF readers (Foxit, Sumatra, web browsers like Chrome etc.) to print out.

I have realized some other people have the same problem, and all it is related to Adobe Reader. However, I couldn't find any solution. As a matter of fact, if someone using Adobe prints the document, plots will be printed incorrectly. To compare, I am attaching the printed paper and the real plot. I am using the newest version of the package.(\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}). I need your help, thank you all.

I made the code much simpler. I should also mention that I tried  print out the same document on two different printers. Thank you all.

A similar problem without an exact solution: [Similar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393234/printing-plot-adds-strange-line)

The simplified code (reproducible):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=TikzPDFs/,shell escape=-enable-write18]
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \pgfplotsset{
        width=14cm,
        height=8.5cm,
        every axis plot/.append style={
        line width=0.9pt,
        },
        legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    }

\tikzsetnextfilename{bst_0model}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
mark options={solid,scale=1},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmin = 0, 
ymin = 0,
xmax=10,
ymax=90,
xlabel={Strain \%},
ylabel={Stress (MPa)},
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={Analytical Solution},
legend pos=south east
]

\addplot [
red,
mark=*,
mark size=2pt,
]coordinates {
(0,0)
(2,62.3)
(10,62.3)
};

\coordinate (insetPosition) at (rel axis cs:0.45,0.01);
 \end{axis}
 
\begin{axis}[ at={(insetPosition)},anchor={outer south east},
footnotesize,
mark options={solid,scale=1},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmin = 9.8, 
ymin =62,
xmax=10,
ymax=62.5,
xtick distance=0.1,
width=4cm
]

\addplot [
red,
mark=*,
mark size=2pt,
]coordinates {
(0,0)
(2,62.3)
(10,62.3)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I see in PDF file:

[image]

What printed out by using Adobe Reader:

[image]

Comment: We can't reproduce your code without the table data... could you add them and, at the same time, try to reduce the example to the minimum removing the parts that do not fail?

Comment: You can use the `filecontents` environment to include some of your table data directly in the TeX code. Then we can reproduce your code.

Comment: Sir, I have simplified latex code. Now it is reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar question actually can solve the problem for MWE, however I don't know if it work for your real case. You can try similar thing in your real case to limit the domain only for the last two points I guess to see if this works. This seems like a bug. What I do is add option to the second axis.

```
\begin{axis}[at={(insetPosition)},anchor={outer south east},
footnotesize,
mark options={solid,scale=1},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
restrict x to domain = 2:10, % add this
restrict y to domain = 62:63, % add this
xmin =9.8, 
ymin =62,
xmax=10,
ymax=62.5,
%xtick distance=0.1, % don't needed
width=4cm
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. A very sad bug for such a nice package, similar issues have been mentioned since 2011. For my case, the solution you underlined is sufficient. I hope the bug will be removed by someone in the future. Thank you again

Comment: @ayb You are welcome. I feel the same for the student that write a thesis and realize something wrong only after they printed the thesis.